# Parse Query from somebody thats not logged in

Tags: parse-platform

I am using a Parse.Query to look up a record with javascript.
It works fine if the user making the query is logged in, but if its just a random unlogged in user making the query, it returns an empty set of results []

```
var userquery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userquery.equalTo("username", "johndoe");
```

Is there something I need to do to enable random people who hit my webpage to run parse queries?

Also, even if I'm logged in. I can't query for a user besides my own. It also returns []

This describes my same problem, but there is no solution: https://www.parse.com/questions/querying-on-parseuser-object-always-returns-empty-array

Comment: I'm only use to using Parse in C# and Java, but I know from them that there are certain permissions on the User object to stop you editting any other User except for the current user. I don't think this applies to just querying for Users though. Maybe check through the User section of the Javascript documentation, see if there are any clues there?

Answer (score 0):

The `User` class is restricted for very good security reasons. It would be quite a security hole if unauthenticated users could query the user table and get even partial login credentials.

If you really need some of the information to be open to unauthenticated users you should put it in another class with no security and link to it from the `User` class.